# Null bitmap is set when there is no null columns

Tags: sql-server, dbcc, data-paging

I am learning PAGE structure and currently I'm stuck at the NULL bitmaps.

```
create table dbo.ro
(
ID int not null,
Col1 varchar(8000) null,
Col2 varchar(8000) null
);
insert into dbo.ro(ID, Col1, Col2) values
(1,replicate('a',8000),replicate('b',8000));
```

So currently there is no NULL values, let's see DBCC info:

```
DBCC IND(test, 'ro', 1);
DBCC PAGE('test',1, 408,3);
```

[image]
So I am interested in the following part
30000800 01000000 03005002

- 30 - BitsA
- 00 - BitsB
- 0800 - Fdata length
- 01000000 - Fixed data (ID = 1)
- 0300 - number of columns
- 50 - NULL bitmap

Why is it 50 and not 00? There is no NULL values in the record ...

Comment: You're parsing it wrong. The final bytes are `03 00 50 02`. The null bitmap is `50`, not `05`. The bottom three bits are `0`. The other bits should be ignored.

Comment: Only the lower three bits are relevant. The bitmap could be `F8`, `98`, `20` or any other value and it would still mean the same thing. The code handling null bitmaps may simply not take care of zeroing out irrelevant bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was in the comment and I upvoted it, but you still have a question so maybe I should explain you what does it mean.

> The bottom three bits are 0. The other bits should be ignored.

If you expand 50 into a binary you've got 01010**000**.
The only bits of interest are **the bottom three bits**, these correspond to 3,2,1 columns that are not null. **The other bits should be ignored** means the server knows the number of colums, it's 3, and it cares only about 3 bits in this mask. Other bits are not set, for that they should be ignored. They just contain a garbage.

Comment: Is this "garbage" logic documented somewhere?

Comment: I think no, it's obvious. Unless you use the data page for the first time + your instance zeroed out data file before usage, all subsequent page usages do not zero it out and you just overwrite what was written there before. You can prove it to yourself inserting more rows and examining the nullbitmap in that rows: it can be different, but the bottom 3 bits are always 0. Or I can give you this link, search it for "crap-shoot" and read around it: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-null-bitmap-size/